# error 1054 - Unknown column "Store.Orders_ID" in "on clause"

Tags: mysql

I am working on a database for a games rental shop. Everything is working fine apart one thing. When I try to JOIN Orders(table) ON Staff(table) it shows error "Unknown column "Staff.Orders_ID" in "on clause" ". Now I worked around and I JOIN'ed Staff(table) ON Orders(table). Everything works fine apart of Salary query where It takes the salary from Orders(table) hence the sum of salary will increase with each sale. Not sure if my tables are connected properly with the foreign keys or something.

Store Table

```
USE `mydb` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Store` (
  `Store_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  

      `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Country` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `City` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `Phone` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
      `Email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `Store_Rent` DECIMAL(9.2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 500,
      `Store_Utilities` DECIMAL(9.2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 200,

  `Last_Update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Store_ID`))     
 ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Inventory table

```
USE `mydb` ;                                        
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Inventory` (
  `Inventory_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

      `Title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT "UNKNOWN TITLE",
      `Rental_Rate_Per_Day` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 5.99,
      `Supplier_Cost` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 29.99,
      `Units_in_Stock` INT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
      `Store_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

   `Last_Update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   INDEX `fk_Inventory_Store_idx` (`Store_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,

   CONSTRAINT `fk_Inventory_Store`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Store_ID`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Store` (`Store_ID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,

PRIMARY KEY (`Inventory_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Staff Table

```
USE `mydb` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Staff` (
`Staff_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 

      `Date_Joined` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Country` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `City` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `Phone` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
      `Email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `Salary` DECIMAL(9.2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 2000,
      `Store_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  INDEX `fk_Staff_Store_idx` (`Store_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Staff_Store`
      FOREIGN KEY (`Store_ID`)
      REFERENCES `mydb`.`Store` (`Store_ID`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  `Last_Update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`Staff_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Orders Table

```
USE `mydb` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Orders` (
`Orders_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  

      `Order_Date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `Store_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `Staff_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `Inventory_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    
      `Customer_ID` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `Return_Date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
      -- `Rental_Number_of_Days` INT(5) NOT NULL,
      `Quantity` INT(3) NOT NULL,


 `Last_Update` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Orders_ID`),

 INDEX `fk_Orders_Store_idx` (`Store_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
 INDEX `fk_Orders_Staff_idx` (`Staff_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
 INDEX `fk_Orders_Inventory_idx` (`Inventory_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
 INDEX `fk_Orders_Customer_idx` (`Customer_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,

 CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_Store`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Store_ID`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Store` (`Store_ID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_Customer`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_ID`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Customer` (`Customer_ID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_Staff`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Staff_ID`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Staff` (`Staff_ID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_Inventory`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Inventory_ID`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Inventory` (`Inventory_ID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
 ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

The Query

```
USE `mydb` ;
CREATE VIEW Expenses_All AS 

SELECT  Store.Name AS "Store Name", 
        CAST(SUM(Inventory.Supplier_Cost * Inventory.Units_in_Stock) AS 
        DECIMAL(5.2)) AS "Value of Games in Stock",
        CAST(SUM(Inventory.Rental_Rate_Per_Day * Orders.Quantity * 
        (datediff(Return_Date, Order_Date))) AS DECIMAL(5.2)) AS "Sales in 
        Euro",
        CAST(SUM(Salary) AS DECIMAL(5.2)) AS "Monthly Salaries",
        Store_Rent AS "Monthly Rent Pay",
        Store_Utilities AS "Monthly Utilities Pay",
        CAST((SUM(Inventory.Rental_Rate_Per_Day * Orders.Quantity * 
        (datediff(Return_Date, Order_Date)))) - Store_Rent - Store_Utilities 
        - (SUM(Salary)) AS DECIMAL(5.2)) AS "Monthly Profit"

    /*  

    FROM (((Store  -- <-- Unknown column "Store.Orders_ID" in "on clause"
        LEFT JOIN Staff ON Store.Staff_ID = Staff.Staff_ID)
        LEFT JOIN Inventory ON Store.Inventory_ID = Inventory.Inventory_ID)
        LEFT JOIN Orders ON Store.Orders_ID = Orders.Orders_ID)

    GROUP BY Store.Store_ID;   

    */

    FROM (((Orders -- <-- This gives me the wrong salary
        LEFT JOIN Staff ON Orders.Staff_ID = Staff.Staff_ID)
        LEFT JOIN Inventory ON Orders.Inventory_ID =Inventory.Inventory_ID)
        LEFT JOIN Store ON Orders.Store_ID = Store.Store_ID)

    GROUP BY Store.Store_ID;
```

[Photo with the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRWiI.png)

Comment: Try removing the extra / additional 3 parenthesis in your FROM / JOIN clauses. I don't think they're needed in your example.

Comment: Indeed, the 3 parenthesis doesn't matter, but the issue persists. Thank you tho

Comment: Basically, this join combo only works if I initiate it from ORDERS (table). Otherwise, I get 1054 error. Not sure its supposed to be like this

Comment: And just to get the obvious question out of the way - are you sure your Store table has an Orders_ID column? You have not included the Store table definition, but it would seem the wrong way and your FK seems to indicate your Orders would have a Store reference (which is also how I suspect it should be).

Comment: I added the column with Orders_ID to the Store but I can't reference it back to Orders because I referenced Store from Orders. If this makes any sense :P

Comment: It is weird because I can go from the Orders table and query anything in Store Table, like Name, Country, City etc but when it gets to the Salary it stops in the Orders and adds up only the selling person Salary

Comment: I added a picture above, just for a test, I made 4 sales with the same employee, on the first line, the SUM is only his salary. Total staff salary should be €9985.